# Can an 8GB RAM Postgres server be used as a lookup that supports 10K queries per second?

Tags: database, postgresql, redis, memcached, lookup

We need to store some lookup tables in a database. The total size of this database won't become too big (e.g. roughly 4 tables, each with 3 columns (mostly strings), with each table having less than 2000 rows).

We need to be able to perform lookups based on incoming messages so that we can parse and write each message into a correct destination.

Rough back of the envelope:

- We want to design for 10,000 messages per second, nonstop streaming in
- All 4 tables need to be accessed (So is that 10,000 x 4
  lookups per second?)
- 4tables x 3columns/table x 2000rows/table x 128bytes/"cell" = approximately 3 million bytes in the entire database?

My question is can an 8GB RAM Postgres server fulfill this demand? Can Postgres basically put the entire database into memory? Or should we look into something like Redis or Memcache?

Comment: Well, do you need the functionality PostgreSQL offers? Consistent snapshots, MVCC, row locking, transactional updates, crash safety, etc etc? All that comes at a cost, especially in terms of number of concurrent queries/clients that can be supported at a time. If you only need a very simple store, another tool may be a better option.